# How to launch an application using a URL link from a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What link should be used and how to determine the right one for every OS?

- iOS
- Android
- Windows
- macOS
- Linux

Is this universal for all operating systems?

```
<!-- Deep link URL for existing users with app already installed on their device -->
    window.location = 'yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx';
```

Comment: Lets see some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is named Uniform Resource Identifier (aka URI).

The beginning of your URL "yourapp" would be a scheme. There are some schemes which are much used, for example ftp:, file:, mailto:, tel:, git:.

There are a lot of it but the support is very limited and as you said, depends on the browser and what software the client has installed on it. So, the scheme has nothing to do with the OS when you use a predefined scheme. If you want to have your own application you need to tell the OS "Uhm, hi there, could you please listen to that scheme" (As example in Windows with the Registry). And you can't do that from the browser because that would open a lot of possible attacks from the browser to your OS.

So to answer your questions: The right one for every OS? Is this universal? Yes, You need only one scheme, as it does not depend on the OS.

Think about it: What do you want to archive? A mailto:? Just do it. A ftp:? Well, your client has to have a FTP-Client with URI-Support. A custom app, like myapp:? That's a lot of work and I wish you good luck with that as it is a custom program for every OS.

If interested, see [this link](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) for a list of all schemes.

I hope, I could help you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I'd like for an app to be installed on the OS, let's call it MyApp. When MyApp is installed it also tells the OS to listen to "myapp://...". If you haven't installed MyApp and click the link nothing happens. If MyApp is installed the link from the web browser should open MyApp. My question is: Can I tell every major OS to listen to "myapp://"? Do all major web browsers support this kind of links?

Comment: This but for every major OS: https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq/ios-custom-url-scheme

Comment: @Vulkan That should work if you ask me, as example WhatsApp uses whatsapp:// but idk if that URI is working on mobile AND desktop (and i am not an expert, maybe someone is nice and shares their knowledge / experience with us - would be awesome)... Btw, here is a nice to know [RFC document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2718) with guidelines.